# HTML Math website

Tags: html

So i am working on a Math website for School. Now, I'm creating a button where its gonna check whats the value in a textbox i just made. And in the script it would check if it was the answer which id Write in the code myself, and the once its pressed, a message-box comes up, saying "Wrong!" or "Correct!". How would i do this? Dont mind the part of it being Norwegian though.

http://pastebin.com/VB7YvrEK

Comment: `if(val = 2)` You fail already. Re-learn the basics and try again.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Niet's comment, the `=` in `if(val = 2)` is an assignment operator. You want a comparison operator. Have a look at [MDN's guide to Expressions and Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators).

This question is far too general. You need to read some articles or books on the basics, i.e. HTML, CSS, and Javascript, or take some interactive lessons online, e.g. on [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/). You can't expect someone to create an entire website for you and post it here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree. Most likely you would have to look for tutorials on how to do this. It's general. Since you're writing that part of your code in javascript, look up javascript tutorials to help guide you.